# Multiple users with unique session IDs in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies

We are trying to perform load testing with multiple users having unique session IDs, users should be unique. We are trying to do the following steps

1. Login
2. Search by ID
3. Submit that request.
4. Logout.

We are trying to do something like this in JMeter

```
Test Plan
  Thread Group
  HTTP Header Manager
  HTTP Request Default
  Http Cookie Manager
  CSV Data Set (Login User Names)
  Transction Controller
    CSV Data Set (Containing ID${__ThreadNum} as filename)
    HTTP Sampler (Login)
    Loop controller
      HTTP Sampler (Search by ID)
      HTTP Sampler ( Submit)
  Http Sampler (Logout)
```

The problem is that it works fine with the user by which the recording/scripting is done, and does not produce the intended results with other users. e.g. If I have recorded the script with **User1**, then it will search and submit from **user1** only. For other users e.g. **User2** and **User3** it will product empty/No results in the search and submit request's response.

If I record it from `User2` than it will start working for `user2` and will not work for `user1`

Any help please. I think there is some problem related to session or cookies. Kindly can anyone please let me know what is the best practice to use Cookie Manager? And any suggestions for this problem

Comment: Well I cannot Post an image here (Great) to show the hierarchy of my test plan. So I cannot post my question properly here. It will be appreciated if anyone can answer my question with the hierarchy messed up above

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are missing some correlation work where some dynamic ID(s) must be extracted from Response in Body or Header to be injected in next request.

Use View Results Tree to see what differs between the recording and the replay, search for IDs in cookies, headers, parameters.